# Test method fails to retrieve data

Tags: unit-test

I'm encountering this kind of error

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

when try to run the test

```
@isTest   private class AccExt2Test {  @isTest  private static void testExt2() {
    Account acc = [select id,name from account where name like 'Edg%' limit 1];
    Test.startTest();
    Pagereference pageRef = Page.FunWithControllers;
    pageRef.getParameters().put('id', acc.id);
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
    AccExt2 controller = new AccExt2(new ApexPages.StandardController(acc));
    Test.stopTest();
    system.assertEquals(controller.acc.id, acc.id );
}
```

}

What's wrong with my code?

```
Account acc = [select id,name from account where name like 'Edg%' limit 1];
```

system.debug(acc);

this code gets me Account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most records in an org are not visible to tests. You need to insert your own records in your test.

Why? This makes tests self-contained rather than them relying on pre-existing data. It also usually makes assertions easier to write because the data values added are close at hand in the test.

See e.g. [Create Test Data for Apex Tests](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_data).